# Android Market and APK file name

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Does it matter what I name the final .apk file that I will be uploading to the android market? Can the user see the name of the file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, name of `.apk` file is ignored and user will not be able to see it. You can name `.apk` in whatever way is convenient for you. Android Market only parses the internals of `.apk` files and extracts all the information it needs.

Also, when `.apk` is installed on the device it named as `<package.name>-#.apk`. For example: `com.google.zxing.client.android-2.apk` or `com.estrongs.android.taskmanager-1.apk`. Though this is not documented and just an observation.

Comment: As a follow up, can I change the name of this file after uploading to the market? i.e. version 1 named app.apk, version 2 named app2.apk, will this cause issues as I publish to the Android market?

Comment: Yes, android market should ignore apk name. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: @segfault Yes, I tested it. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have noticed the package name of app on the prompt message when application got crashed.
2. Package name is also visible for some time, when device is loading package screen in settings. If device is acting slow, I can see the package name of the application.

So you can take care of package name.

Comment: You are right, but package name doesn't equals .apk file name.

Comment: Yes true. Package name and APK name are different things.