# Android application name

Tags: android, google-play

I have a doubt regarding application name on Android. I am going to upload my application to the Android market. Before that I want to know whether the application name (in other words app_name) can contain spaces or not?. If app name contains spaces, what are the problems may arise after releasing APK to the market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can contain spaces, even the [example app](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) contains (search for "app_name"). You will have no problems.

Comment: Example app may contain spaces for app_name, because example app may not going to release through android market. I got information that if app name contains spaces then there will be a problem in android market. please provide information regarding android market filters . I want to know whether market filters works on app_name???

Comment: Start your Android phone, and check how many apps have space in their names. Serously dont worry about this, it has nothing to do with market filters.

Comment: apk name does not matter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245858/android-market-and-apk-file-name

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I can use apk name with spaces also right???.
Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at AndroidManifest.xml and you'll see something like this

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

...

</application>
```

So, just changing variable **app_name** in your /res/values/strings.xml is enough. Spaces are allowed.
Do not forget to reinstall your application otherwise it might crash!

Comment: My app_name variable is set to (for example) "ProjectName" but the launcher's label still says "MainActivity".  What gives?

Comment: @shim Did you try to uninstall your application completely from your device? Though I could not to reinstall, I just saw launcher's label change immediately after changing **app_name** variable.

Comment: You just have to delete the label from the MainActivity so that it uses the application one, or you have to set the mainactivity label to match the app name.

Comment: @shim Actually I've just tested it and it is enough to set new resource string in **strings.xml** and set it as activity title: **android:label="@string/activity_name"**. Since I have one single activity in application, this string is set as Launcher's label. Not **app_name** which is used as application name, but **activity_name** - activity label. Working on Android 2.3.3